# THREE.js won't to load my .mtl and .obj file

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, three.js, objloader

I'm trying to create a 3d model viewer by using three.js but it won't load any .mtl and .obj files. I followed this tutorial https://manu.ninja/webgl-3d-model-viewer-using-three-js/ but it only loads the female model.

This is my script:

```
            var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
            mtlLoader.setBaseUrl('models/rayman2');
            mtlLoader.setPath('models/rayman2');
            mtlLoader.load('rayman_2_mdl.mtl', function (materials) {

                materials.preload();

                materials.materials.default.map.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
                materials.materials.default.map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

                var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
                objLoader.setPath('models/rayman2');
                objLoader.load('rayman_2_mdl.obj', function (object) {

                    object.position.x = 0;
                    object.position.y = 0;
                    object.position.z = 0;
                    scene.add(object);

                }, null, null);

            });
```

Comment: Please attach the model or a demo link with the model that isn't working, otherwise we cannot reproduce the problem. And use the error callbacks ([see docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/OBJLoader)) and describe any errors that you see beyond just "won't load."

Comment: https://www.models-resource.com/dreamcast/rayman2thegreatescape/model/17577/ this is the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [convert the file to glTF here](https://cesiumjs.org/convertmodel.html), then load it as follows:

```
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load('rayman.glb', function (gltf) {
  var content = gltf.scene;
  content.traverse((node) => {
    if (!node.isMesh) return;
    node.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
    node.material.alphaTest = 0.25;
    node.material.needsUpdate = true;
  });
  scene.add(content);
}, undefined, function (e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

The conversion to glTF just simplifies things. The other changes fix issues in the model: `THREE.DoubleSide` ensures that both sides of the character's hair are visible, and `alphaTest` ensures that the transparency in the texture appears correctly.

[image]

See docs for [THREE.Material](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/Material) and [THREE.GLTFLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/GLTFLoader).

three.js r92.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a terrible time trying to figure this out as well. The fix I found that worked was completely rediculous, number 1, make sure your image scale is set to 1 but it seems yours is the default, here is the rediculous thing....

```
mtlLoader.setBaseUrl('models/rayman2');
mtlLoader.setPath('models/rayman2');
```

is incorrect, you will need to add a / at the end of your paths so it would appear as follows:

```
mtlLoader.setBaseUrl('models/rayman2/');
mtlLoader.setPath('models/rayman2/');
```

I changed this on my project and somehow, it worked